# Is codeigniter's url encoding here necessary?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, uri

I'm passing a string from one page to another, is the url encoding necessary here?

**Like so:**

```
<?=anchor('foo/bar/'.$id.'/'.$title, 'All')?>

function bar($id, $title) {
   $data['id'] = $id;
   $data['title'] = $title;
   $this->load->view('some_view', $data);
}
```

As you can see these variables have no interaction with a database. What is the best way to decode these variables?

Comment: What do you mean, decode the variables? the variables *are* 'decoded'. You've assigned them to the $data array...

Comment: Ok, the $id variable need not be encoded. The $title, yes, it would. However... is the $id related to the $title in any way? Why not do a $title lookup on the server based on the $id that is clicked. It's generally bad practice to throw long strings of text around like this.

Comment: I was hoping to hit the database less.

Comment: Not a very good technique to get yourself into. What happens when the title also has a description, an author, a rating, etc. You're not going to want to hand those around the URL. Use the ID, look the rest of the details up on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - what if one person gives someone else a link to `site.com/foo/bar/3/<script...`? (Answer: it'll probably be caught by some other part of CI doing the escaping for you, but still :P)

Always escape **all** user input, even if you don't think it matters, because you can't be certain.

Comment: Have another look at your last 2 comments :) Use backticks (left of the 1 key) around any code you want to enter.

Comment: Considering the spaces in the variable after going through controller foo become %20 CI must be encoding the data

Comment: Nope, that's just your browser encoding them as it sends the GET request for the next page.

Comment: oh I'm sorry don't you speaketh liketh *thee

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7512/discussion-between-amiawizard-and-joe)